# Can I use LINQ to get more than 100 records back from a Quickbooks Online ServiceContext?

Tags: c#, linq, quickbooks-online

For my Quickbooks Online integration, I'm using the .NET SDK and was previously using LINQ to access data from a `ServiceContext`:

```
var paymentMethodsService = new QueryService<PaymentMethod>(ServiceContext);
_paymentMethods = paymentMethodsService.Select(x => x).ToList();
```

When testing, we noticed that this only returns the first 100 records. (Presumably because this is the default page size?)

We can get around this by using a query containing `MAXRESULTS`:

```
var itemsService = new QueryService<Item>(ServiceContext);
_items = itemsService.ExecuteIdsQuery("SELECT * FROM Item MAXRESULTS 1000").ToList();
```

My question is, can I achieve the same result without using a query string?

Comment: Do you have more than 100 records in the database?  Did you try the string query to see if you got back more data?

Comment: @jdweng Yes the query string returns 300+ records, so it's not the end of the world if there's no other way. Would just prefer to avoid a hard coded query string if possible.

Comment: And what if you do `Take(10000).Select(...)`?

Comment: @Evk D'oh! This is what I get for posting to Stack on a Friday afternoon. Of course that works. If you want to put that into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit I have no idea what Quickbooks Online even is, but nevertheless I think you can override default page size with LINQ `Take(yourPageSize)`. Though it's still not clear how to fetch ALL items in a collection this way, without knowing total count beforehand. Hopefully you don't need to do this in your scenario (or if you do - maybe you can just use arbitrary large number for `Take` if you won't find another way).

Comment: The bit you don't (couldn't) know is that 1,000 is the maximum allowed page size. In my case I'm not expecting the list to ever have more than this number of entries, but I'll be adding a check that calls `.Skip(1000)` when 1,000 elements are returned to my first call.